# combining file chunk hash value to file fingerprint

Tags: hash, sha256

We need a file fingerprint for all uploaded files in server. Now, sha256 is chosen to be the hash function.

For large files, each file is split into several file chunks of equal size (except the last one) to transfer. sha256 values of each file chunk are provided by clients. They are re-calculated and checked by server.

However, those sha256 values cannot be combined into the sha256 value for the whole file.

So I consider changing the definition of file fingerprint:

For files smaller than 1GB, the sha256 value is the fingerprint.

For files larger than 1GB, it is sliced into 1GB chunks. Each chunk has its own sha256 value, denoted as s0, s1, s2 (all are integer value).

When the first chunk received:

`h0 = s0`

When second chunk received

`h1 = SHA256(h0 << 256 + s1)`

This is essentially concatenating two hash values and hash it again. This process is repeated until all chunks received. And the final value `hn` is used as the file fingerprint.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I have googled a lot. And read a few articles on combine_hash functions in various languages or frameworks. Different author chooses different bit mangling hash functions and most of them are said to be working well.

In my case, however, the efficiency is not a concern. But the fingerprint is stored and used as the file content identifier system-wide.

My primary concern is if the naive method listed above will introduce more conflicts than sha256 itself?

If sha256 is not a good choice for combining hash values in our case, is there any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially reinventing [Merkle tree](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Merkle_tree).

What you'll have to do is to split your large files into equally-sized chunks (sans last fragment), compute hash for each of those chunks, and then combine them pairwise until there is a single ultimate hash value. Note that the "root" hash *will not* be equal to the hash of the original file, but that's not required to validate the integrity of the entire file.

Comment: I understand the final hash is not equal to the sha256 value of the whole file. But my concern is if it will introduce MORE conflicts as the file fingerprint?

Comment: @matianfu I'm no mathematician/cryptographer, but the fact that Git, Mercurial, BitTorrent and other applications and protocols are built on Merkle trees is a living proof that they do work reliably.

Comment: Yeah, you proposed strong proof. Now I think the method is safe enough for our application. Thanks.